# What is the appropriate SOAP Action?

Tags: soap, coldfusion

I am using Coldfusion 8. I have exceedingly limited experience with SOAP.

I am trying to send out a SOAP request.  My SOAP body looks like this:

```
<cfsavecontent variable="SoapBody">
<cfoutput>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"     xmlns:v2="http://www.a2zshow.com/DataServices/v2/" >
<soapenv:Header>
<a2zAuthenticationHeader xmlns="http://www.a2zshow.com/DataServices/v2/">
<Key>#Key#</Key>
<UserName>#UserName#</UserName>
<Password>#Password#</Password>
<InstallName>#InstallName#</InstallName>
</a2zAuthenticationHeader>
</soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body>
<DataService xmlns="http://www.a2zshow.com/DataServices/ExhibitorListRequest/v1">
<Request>
<a2zXMLRootNode>
<RequestHeader>
<RequestAttribute Search="NONE"/>
</RequestHeader>
<RequestCriteria>
<EventID>#EventID#</EventID>
</RequestCriteria>
</a2zXMLRootNode>
</Request>
</DataService>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
</cfoutput>
</cfsavecontent>
```

My SOAP request looks like this:

```
<cfhttp
url="#PostURL#"
method="post"
result="httpResponse">
<cfhttpparam 
    type="header" 
    name="SOAPAction" 
    value="#SOAPAction#" />
<cfhttpparam
    type="xml"
    value="#trim(soapBody)#"/>
</cfhttp>
```

The SOAPAction variable is set like this:

```
SOAPAction = "http://www.a2zshow.com/getExhibitorList";
```

I think I am successfully posting to the right place, but I am getting an error message saying that client didn't recognize the SOAPAction.  Here's my error:

```
soap:ClientServer did not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction: http://www.a2zshow.com/getExhibitorList.
```

This error seems to be telling me that I don't have the SOAPAction correct. The guy at the other end tells me that I have everything set up right and that it should be working. Is there something missing?

Comment: have you tried sending across the soapBody as `type="body"` instead of xml? I had a similar issue last week where I was sending across the body as the wrong type.

Comment: I just tried that with no luck. I am sure I am stuck at having the wrong SOAPAction, but our vendor is being unresponsive. I just need to know if I am doing something that is obviously wrong.

Comment: Have you tried setting "http://www.a2zshow.com/" as the POSTURL and "getExhibitorList" as the SOAP ACTION?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was in the vendor's SOAPAction. They gave me the wrong URL. Their documentation was created 8 years ago and they updated it in 2008.

I guess they would rather spend time making their product hard to use by confusing people with the wrong information than to help get something done.

Thanks for the help!